# Error: Unable to display RD Web Access... after hitting refresh in IE

Tags: rdp, internet-explorer, windows-server-2012-r2, remote-desktop-services

Just setup a RDS environment with Windows Server 2012 R2 (Broker/WebAccess/RDSH/Gateway/SSL).

Everything works, except for when you hit the `Refresh` button on the browser on any page, you will get the following error:

```
Error: Unable to display RD Web Access

An unexpected error has occurred that is preventing this page from
being displayed correctly.

Viewing this page in Internet Explorer with the Enhanced Security
Configuration enabled can cause such an error.

Please try loading this page without the Enhanced Security
Configuration enabled. If this error continues to be displayed, please
contact your administrator.
```

Now Enhanced Security Configuration is/was turned off on the server. Turned it on, and then off with no luck. Turn it on for admins, but off for users...etc... still I get the same error.

This error only happens with IE, not using another browser (Chrome/Firefox are fine).
Turned off Protected Mode in IE.
Restarted the IIS web server.

This [post](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsserver/en-US/09fd46ae-783d-4880-a405-3f98c45b652d/errors-on-rd-web-access?forum=winserverTS) mentions the error and `Enhanced Security Configuration` fix, but it does not work for me.

Comment: What version of IE? I get a handful of errors, including this one, that are due to the new IE. Have you tried adding the site to the Compatibility View list?

Comment: Tried only a couple clients, they were using IE 9.

Comment: Is there any load balancing on the web access roles?

Answer (score 1):

Well, rebooting the server did the trick :-/